# Cannot mount ISO file in Windows Server 2012

Tags: mount, iso-image

I am using VMware Player to run a Windows 2012 Server Standard Build 9200. I  need to mount an ISO image. The server does not seem to recognize that it is an ISO file and wants me to tell it how to open it. 
I know I could install a third-party application, but Windows 2012 already supports this feature.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Option to mount .iso in Windows 8 missing](http://superuser.com/questions/497429/option-to-mount-iso-in-windows-8-missing), also see [Is it possible to mount an ISO image in Windows 8 without third-party software?](http://superuser.com/questions/495472/is-it-possible-to-mount-an-iso-image-in-windows-8-without-third-party-software?rq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thank you for your comment.  These questions are related but not precisely the same issue.  Aside from different operating systems, which would be a search parameter, the details of the cause in the first answer does not apply, and the second is precisely the feature not working.

Comment: @David, even though there are differences in the questions, does the accepted answer in the first one solve the problem?

Comment: @fixer1234, sure...the answer W8 Desktop can be adapted to W12k server, but then so also general questions on programming can adapted to any language...

Comment: FWIW, Had a similar problem with 2012 R2 when mounting an ISO over a network share. ISO mount was running as admin, which didn't have the drive mapped. Using UNC path fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I see that you already figured it out, but for others, here's how you can do it in Powershell:

> Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'D:\Path\To\Image.iso'  -StorageType ISO
>   -PassThru | Get-Volume

The Get-Volume is there so you can see what driver letter gets assigned after you mount it.  This will work in Server Core 2012 R2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing to open the ISO with "Windows Explorer" fixed the issue.